# Plotly Marker Size from CSV

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot

I'm very new to using plotly and need help fine tuning a scatter plot map of New England. I want to increase the size of the markers in my map but can't seem to get it right. Can anyone help?

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go


df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.github.khoury.northeastern.edu/acroak/5800_group_project/main/5800_dataset.csv?token=GHSAT0AAAAAAAAANVYK5KIZUPNUSFWYMFPAZCLXTFQ')

print(df.head(10))
print(df.tail(10))

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df,
                        lon = df['long'], 
                        lat = df['lat'],
                        hover_name = df['Place'],
                        zoom = 7,
                        width = 1200,
                        height = 900,
                        size_max = 25,
                        title = 'Spooky Map')

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0, "t":50, "l":0, "b":10})
fig.show()
```

So far, I have tried using size and size_max as parameters in fig but that didn't do anythin.

Comment: Your data frame does not have the column data to set the size of the marker. Please add a column for the size and specify the grandfathered column name. If this is your data, try the ID column.`fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df,...,size_max = 25,size='ID',title = 'Spooky Map')`

Comment: Alternatively, it can be done by specifying a listing for the number of rows in the data frame. `fig=px.scatter_mapbox(df,....size=[20]*len(df),....)`